# How can I add custom right click option in Outlook VSTO Plugin?

Tags: wpf, windows, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

In my mailbox I will select text and right click on context menu there will be custom added option 'go'. And there will be an event handler attached with go button to perform operations on selected text.

Seen documentation and examples but didn't find any good solution. How can I add custom right click option in outlook vsto plugin.

Comment: Right click where? A selected message in one of the folders? Preview pane? Message body in an inspector?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Like I am in outlook inbox.selected some text from inbox mail and right click is pressed. I want to add custom option in context menu of right click